# Count Unique Objects

Tags: elasticsearch, counting, elasticsearch-aggregation

My index looks like this:

```
"_source": {
  "ProductName": "Random Product Name",
  "Views": {
    "Washington": [
      { "4nce5bbszjfppltvc": "2018-04-07T18:25:16.160Z" },
      { "4nce5bba8jfpowm4i": "2018-04-07T18:05:39.714Z" },
      { "4nce5bbszjfppltvc": "2018-04-07T18:36:23.928Z" },
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to count the number of unique objects in `Views.Washington`.
In this case, the result would be **2**, since two objects have the same key names. ( *first and third object in the array* ).

Obviously, my first thought was to use *aggregations*, but I am not sure how to use them with *nested objects*, like these.

Can this be done with *normal aggregations*?
Will I need to *use a script*?

Comment: What is your mapping? What is the query you have tried and what is the response/error if any

Comment: I haven't created a mapping, I add these fields and ES creates the mappings automatically. I have tried many queries, too many to list here, and none of them seem to have worked. I tried aggregations and even scripts, but I am still not sure how to count them. Every query I try gives me either 0 as a count, or doesn't work. Obviously I'm still pretty new to ES.

Comment: Well keep trying that is how you learn. If you are letting ES automap then nested aggregation won't work

Comment: Oh, that is good to know! So, I should create my mappings manually first, and then import data?

Comment: Yes see here for details https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: Alright, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done with Aggregations: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found that piece of documentation but I can't get it to work, hence this post. Could you maybe provide an example of how to implement it in my case?